# Attribute error when calling calling a scipy function

Tags: python, scipy, cdf, norm

I am trying to run the following function defined on a separate python file using jupyter notebook

```
def f(x):
    return 2 * norm.cdf(x)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cdf'
```

However, I am getting an Attribute error. I am not sure what is exactly going on as I imported the module correctly in the .py file.

Comment: What is `norm`?

Comment: scipy.stats.norm

Comment: Most cases when there's an attribute error, it's because the object in question isn't what the programmer thinks it is.  Obviously we can't help with the scant info you provide. Less often the problem is with the reading of the docs or changes with versions.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of `norm()`s in the sea, so your problem is very likely that you are not calling the `norm()` that you think you are. It is always good to be verbose :)

```
import scipy as scp
from scipy import stats

def f(x):
    return 2*scp.stats.norm.cdf(x)
```